Let $x$ and $y$ be non-negative integers such that $N =2^6 + 2^x+2^{3y}$ is a perfect square and $N\leq10,000$. Find the maximum value of $x+y$.
Let x and y be non-negative integers such that $2^{6}+2^{x}+2^{3y}$ is a perfect square, and the expression should be less than 10,000. Find the maximum value of $x+y$

$2^{6}+2^{x}+2^{3y} <= 10,000$, so y must be less than or equal to 4. I can consider each case y=0,1,2,3,4 and solve this integer equation, but the solution is too long.

I would appreciate any help, hint, or approach to get a shorter solution

The problem comes from InIMC Keystage III, according to https://chiuchang.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/01/2017InIMC_Keystage_III_Individual_ENG.x17381.pdf, problem 1, section B from the Individual category


Seems entirely arbitrary.  Anyway,  the raw search isn't all that bad.   Are you forced to do this with pencil and paper?  Are you allowed to "know" the squares less than $10,000$?  Otherwise you have an annoying factoring problem.  Maybe not too bad, given that you can pull out a power of $2$, but still.

$x=4$ and $y=0$ give one solution. From $2^x+2^{3y}=(x-8)(z+8)$ I think that either $\max x=3$ or $\max 3y=3$, but I have not thought this through to a proof.

@KeithBackman  $x=10, y=4$ is a solution since $2^6+2^{10}+2^{12}=2^6\times (1+2^4+2^6)=72^2$.  I think that's maximal

Should say:  looking at the other problems on that contest, this one seems unexpectedly difficult.  Assuming you have to use pencil and paper that is, it's easy with a spreadsheet or calculator.  The others can be done mentally, more or less.  So maybe I'm missing a clever trick here.  I got my large example with pencil and paper, by a "greedy" algorithm, figuring I should take large $x$ and hunt for a viable $y$.  Confirmed with a search.  But maybe there is a more clever way.

@lulu Thanks for the insight. I see that, for example, $2^{6n}(1+2^4+2^6)$ would work in general to yield a square, but that it exceeds the limit of $10,000$ set in the question for $n>1$

@KeithBackman  Don't know how much "insight" was involved, pretty mechanical searching. the only other idea I had was to note that the expression essentially gives us the binary expression for the square, so all you need to do is to determine which of the first $100$ squares have two or three $1's$ (and then check those to make sure they are in good places).  Again, easy to do with a machine, quite tedious by hand.

Here is a solution, follow by @lulu's hint:
Since N <= 10,000, y <= 4
Case 1: $y = 0$
$N = a^{2} = 2^{x} + 65$. We already know that a perfect square must be congruent to 0, 1 or 4 when divided by 5 so $2^{x}$ must be congruent to 1 or 4 when divided by 5 so x must be even.
=> $(a-2^{x/2})(a+2^{x/2}) = 65$ => x = 10 or x = 4 => the maximum value of x + y is 10
Case 2: $y = 1$
$N = a^{2} = 2^{x} + 72$. We already know that a perfect square must be congruent to 0 or 1 when divided by 3 so $2^{x}$ must be congruent to 1 when divided by 3 so x must be even.
$=>(a-2^{x/2})(a+2^{x/2}) = 72$. There is no integer x that satisfies this equation
Case 3: $4>= y >=2$

If x <= 6, x + y <= 6 + 4 = 10
If x > 6:

$N = 2^{6}(1+2^{x-6}+2^{3y-6}) => M = 1+2^{x-6}+8^{(y-2)} <= 156$ and M is a perfect square
Let $m = x-6, n = y-2, 7>=m>=0, 2>=n>=0 => M = a^{2} = 1 + 2^{m} + 8^{n}$
Case 3.1: $n = 0$
$M = 2^{m} + 2$ cannot be a perfect square because it is congruent to 3 or 2 when divided to 4
Case 3.2: $n = 1$
$M = 2^{m} + 9$ => M must be congruent to 1 when divided to 3 => m is even => $(a-2^{m/2})(a+2^{m/2})=9 => 2^{m/2}=4 => m=4 => n + m = 5 => x + y = 13 $
Case 3.3: $n = 2$
$M = 2^{m} + 65$. Similar to case 1, we found m = 10 or m = 4 but m<=7 so m = 4
In this case $x=10, y=4 => x+y=14$
Conclusion:: the maximum value of x + y is 14
